# How to use removeChild() from an XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml

So basically I have a vocabulary system with an XML file to store the words. I want to remove a word when I press on a button. 
My XML file:

```
    <root>
    <word>
        <german>Ich</german>
        <japanese>watashi</japanese>
    </word>
    <word>
        <german>Student</german>
        <japanese>gakusei</japanese>
    </word>
```

Sorry for the weird showcase of the XML file i did not know how to properly make it look just imagine the <> around root word and stuff.

---

And now if i press a remove button i want to delete it. 
My ActionListener(I have some other buttons thats why its else if):

```
else if(e.getSource() == remove) {
        JButton rmv = (JButton) e.getSource();
        for(int i = 1; i < Liste.size() + 2; i++) {
            if(rmv == elemente[i][2]) {

                Liste.remove(i - 1);
                root.removeChild(doc.getElementsByTagName("word")[i - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

the doc.getElementsByTagName("word")[i - 1] Statement says : "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to NodeList"

Thanks in regard

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ ? Method `getElementsByTagName()` does return a `NodeList` and a `NodeList` is **not** and array. Maybe you need method `item(int)` from `NodeList` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void deleteWord(Document doc, String word) {
    // <word>
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("word");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      Element word = (Element)nodes.item(i);

      Element name = (Element)word.getElementsByTagName("japanese").item(0);
      String pName = name.getTextContent();
      if (pName.equals(word)) {
         word.getParentNode().removeChild(word);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found another solution but yours is better. Thanks a lot!